# Threejs convert local X,Y to world co-ordinate

Tags: three.js

I would like to convert a local co-ordinate (X,Y)(not mouse click) to world co-ordinate in Threejs.

Thanks And Regards,
Rupak Banerjee.

Comment: If you want to convert a position from an object's local space to world space, look at [Object3D.localToWorld](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=objec#api/en/core/Object3D.localToWorld). If you want something else, you need to provide more details.

Comment: plane = new THREE.Mesh( planeGeometry, planeMaterial );                                       const a = new THREE.Vector3( xxx, yyy, 35 );
let b = plane.localToWorld(a);     Nothing is happening

Comment: What is the input and what is the expected output? If there is no translation/rotation of the mesh/plane, `b` will be the same as `a`.

Comment: I have an image loaded as Texture with BoxGeometry. Now I want to input a X,Y. My expected output is that X,Y will be translated to X,Y,Z . Meaning converting a 2D point to 3D.

Comment: So, your input is a point on the texture and want to know where this point is in 3D space? Since a simple BoxGeometry projects a texture on each side, there would be 6 possible points in 3D in this case.